# Getting root to point to AWS ELB without using AWS nameservers

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I've set up my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I added a load balancer and pointed a CNAME for 'www' to it.  But now I need to get root pointed there too.  I can't use Route53 and use AWS nameservers because the client wants to use theirs.  How can I get root to my app?  Can I redirect the traffic?  The tech lead I'm working with suggested setting up a server to do the redirect?

Comment: What about http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect?  I have no connection with that service, and I don't use it, because I am usually able to educate my clients that changing their authoritative nameservers to a Route 53 hosted zone *without* transferring their domain (so they clearly still own and control the domain itself) is in their best interests for reliability... but I've tested it, and it seems to serve the purpose.  I love the fact that their FAQ says *"Previous answer is too short. Is there a typo?"*  No, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I can't seem to convince this client.  I will give this a try

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If you create an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since AWS ELB's only offer DNS Record (Instead of IPs) you need to use a CNAME mapping. However with DNS, CNAMEs do not allow root domain to point to it. To overcome this AWS has provided Alias Records (Custom implementation to AWS) to point root domain to ELBs.

If your client want to use their nameservers still you can use, AWS Route53 in between to solve this with following steps.

1. First create a Public Hosted Zone in Route53 for your domain.
2. Then create a record set inside the Hosted Zone for the root domain to point to the ELB with Type = A - IPv4 Address, Alias = Yes with ELB CNAME as for the Alias value.
3. In the external domain management service, create a NS record to point the root domain to Route53 nameservers.

Then when the DNS resolution happens, the root DNS query will first go to  external nameservers(Managed outside of Route53) and then it will be forwarded to route53 where it will resolve the ELBs IP address and sent back.

Comment: *"create a NS record to point the root domain to Route53 nameservers"*  That has the same problem as a CNAME.  It only works consistently for subdomains.

Comment: @Michael  NS record is not for route53 but for external DNS management service.

Comment: I understand that, but an authoritative server can't delegate the apex of its own zone with an NS record.  That only works below the apex (subdomain).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a machine with a single static IP address that does nothing but redirect requests to the www host.  Then you can put an A record on the bare domain at the apex of the DNS zone pointing to that machine.

There is at least one service, http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect, that will do this for you.  (I'm not affiliated with this service, but it appears to do what it claims and will serve your purpose.  There are probably others like it.)

Ideally, though, you'd persuade your client to change the authoritative nameservers to point to a Route 53 hosted zone that you create for them.  They are still the registrant and "owner" of their domain, and can take control back from you by simply changing the nameservers to something else.

I generally persuade clients with the explanation that our load balancer infrastructure is integrated with the DNS servers so that if a balancer node fails, or we need to add or scale up capacity, or experience a traffic surge or DDoS event, the load balancer system will automatically update the DNS records for their domain to try to mitigate the issue and keep the site up.  To do otherwise is to do things in such a way that removes those layers of redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you can set up a apache server with a static IP, and install a free SSL certificate on that web server at first.

Second you need to redirect your root domain name request to AWS ELB.

Then go to your DNS management and set up your apex point to the server you created.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to setup a [Network Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) and allocate one or more Elastic IP Addresses to it (one per Availability Zone). The Network Load Balancer can have an [Application Load Balancer as a target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/application-load-balancer-target.html). The Application Load Balancer would target the Elastic Beanstalk. An A record can then be created in the external DNS for each Elastic IP Address of the Network Load Balancer.

If you don't need the functionality that the Application Load Balancer provides, you may be able to target Elastic Beanstalk or whatever application directly from the Network Load Balancer.